# Why does my function doesnt return numbers larger than 1306, whose still pass the condition?

Tags: javascript

Complete instructions of my exercise are :

"--The number 89 is the first integer with more than one digit that fulfills the property partially introduced in the title of this kata. What's the use of saying "Eureka"? Because this sum gives the same number.

In effect: 89 = 8^1 + 9^2

The next number in having this property is 135.

See this property again: 135 = 1^1 + 3^2 + 5^3

We need a function to collect these numbers, that may receive two integers a, b that defines the range [a, b] (inclusive) and outputs a list of the sorted numbers in the range that fulfills the property described above.--"

I worked pretty hard (at my level indeed) to make this function to work, BUT, it only works until it reach a certain number (1306), but doesn't return the next numbers which are supposed to pass the condition(which is 1676 for the next one). I have no clue why it doesn't work, since i fixed no maximum all over the function. For my exercise, it's supposed to handle correctly for a range of nearby 1 million.

```js
function sumDigPow(a, b) {
  let array = [...Array(b + 1).keys()];
  let result = [];
  array.splice(0, a);
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i].toString().split('').map(Number);
    if (array[i].map(x => Math.pow(x, array[i].indexOf(x) + 1)).reduce((a, b) => a + b) == parseInt(array[i].join(''))) {
      result.push(parseInt(array[i].join('')))
    }
  }
  return result
}


console.log(sumDigPow(1, 3000));
```

For exemple, for "sumDigPow(346, 2471)", result should be '[518, 598, 1306, 1676, 2427]', and instead, i only have the first three ones '[518, 598, 1306]'. Same goes for any input i provide : i only have numbers which pass my condition until 1306, none above.

Comment: please add some examples and the wanted results.

Comment: And also what you are trying to do & executing a function in `if` is very bad practice

Comment: Also, I find it not clear what kind of sequence the function is supposed to generate.

Comment: What is the logic to return `[518, 598, 1306]`

Comment: What do you expect the result to be for `array[i].map(x => Math.pow(x, array[i].indexOf(x) + 1))` with `array[i] = [1, 6, 7, 6]`? Because `indexOf(6)` will return `1` for *both* digits `6`. If you expect to get `1` and `3`, then you'll get a different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this calculation:

```js
array[i].map(x => Math.pow(x, array[i].indexOf(x) + 1))
```

When you get to the number `1676`, it has repeating digit `6`, so `indexOf(6)` will return the first index twice, thus you get

[1<sup>1</sup>, 6<sup>2</sup>, 7<sup>3</sup>, 6<sup>**2**</sup>]

instead of

[1<sup>1</sup>, 6<sup>2</sup>, 7<sup>3</sup>, 6<sup>**4**</sup>]

A similar problem happens with **2**4**2**7.

You can simply use the second argument to the [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback to get the current index:

```js
array[i].map((x, index) => Math.pow(x, index + 1))
```

```js
function sumDigPow(a, b) {
  let array = [...Array(b + 1).keys()];
  let result = [];
  array.splice(0, a);
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i].toString().split('').map(Number);
    if (array[i].map((x, index) => Math.pow(x, index + 1)).reduce((a, b) => a + b) == parseInt(array[i].join(''))) {
      result.push(parseInt(array[i].join('')))
    }
  }
  return result
}


console.log(sumDigPow(1, 3000));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the index instead of searching for the index of the actual number. `indexOf` returns the first found index, but not the position of the actual value.

```
.map((x, i) => Math.pow(x, i + 1))
         ^                 ^
```

```js
function sumDigPow(a, b) {
  let array = [...Array(b + 1).keys()];
  let result = [];
  array.splice(0, a);
       
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var value = array[i];
    array[i] = array[i].toString().split('').map(Number);
    if (array[i]
        .map((x, i) => Math.pow(x, i + 1))
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b) == value
    ) {
      result.push(parseInt(array[i].join('')))
    }
  }
  console.log(a, b)
  return result
}


console.log(sumDigPow(1, 3000));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```